# routing based on source IP

Tags: linux, rhel, routing

Is it possible to configure routing based on source ip? For example, if I have source IP *10.0.0.0*, then all the traffic will go via the specific interface or would be sent to specific default gateway.

I am not clear about the details provided [here](http://openvz.org/Source_based_routing). I do not find any description on the table from the above link. Also, I need to setup this routing as static.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: redhat operating system

Comment: @user1977050 What is unclear about the link you posted? It gives you an example and explains what each command in the example means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one *default* gateway specified in `/etc/sysconfig/network`:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=<fqdn>
GATEWAY=<gateway ip address>
```

Static route configuration is defined in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-<interface>.` There is [good documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-static-routes.html) on the RedHat website. These files almost always look like this:

```
<ip address>/<subnet mask> via <ip address of interface>
```

There are trickier ways like using named tables. This way (in the same `route-<interface>` files) looks like this:

```
table my_management_network to <ip address>/<subnet mask> dev <interface> proto kernel scope link src <ip address of interface>
```

This way also needs a new file, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/rule-<interface>`:

```
from <ip address>/<subnet mask> lookup my_management_network
```

Restart the network stack to apply changes (`service network restart`). (Or, are you using NetworkManager?) Have you configured `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<device>` files statically, too, without specifying `DEFROUTE` in them?

```
DEVICE=<device>
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
NOZEROCONF=yes
IPADDR=<ip address of interface>
NETMASK=<subnet mask of interface>
```